# Exercise with complex projective line

Tags: differential-geometry, projective-geometry

Let $x$, $y$, $z$, $t$ be the standard coordinates for $\mathbb R^4$ and $f:S^3 \to \mathbb {CP}^1$ , with $f(x,y,z,t)=[x+iy:z+it]$. I have to show that $f$ is $C^\infty$ and, given $p:=(1,0,0,0),$ calculate $df_p$ in the coordinates. I have no clue how to do this exercise, because I don't even know what does the notation with the square brackets mean; I didn't find any result searching on Google neither. Can you explain how the function $f$ is defined? Thank you in advance

Comment: $\mathbb{CP}^1$ is, by definition, the set of all $\mathbb{C}\lambda$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}^2$ nonzero. If $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$, $\mathbb{C}\lambda$ is denoted as $[\lambda_1:\lambda_2]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brackets are homogeneous coordinates. Recall how projective spaces are defined (will do it in the complex case here): You start with $\mathbb{C}^{n+1} \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ and then quotient out the group action of $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ operating by multiplication. Thus elements of $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{C})$ are given by equivalence classes of non-zero $(n+1)$-tuples, where you change representatives by multiplying with non-zero complex numbers. These equivalence classes are the brackets. For example we have $[1:2:3:i] = [i:2i:3i:-1] \in \mathbb{P}^3(\mathbb{C})$. By that we achieved that a point in the projective space corresponds to a line in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, namely the $1$-dimensional subspace generated by any representative of the point.

Do you understand that map now?

Comment: Yes, now I understand the map so I'll try to do the  exercise; thank you very much!

Comment: The first point is easy to prove: the inclusion of $S^3$ in $\mathbb R^4 \simeq \mathbb C^2$ and the projection of $\mathbb C^2$ on $\mathbb {CP}^1 $ are both $C^\infty$. However, when I calculate the differential I would use the composition $f\circ \phi$ with $\phi :S^3_+\to \mathbb R^3$; here $S^3_+ $ is the part of $S^3$ with $t\geq 0$ and $\phi(s_1,s_2,s_3)=(s_1,s_2,s_3,\sqrt{1-s_1^2-s_2^2-s_3^2})$

Comment: Then I calculate $d(f\circ \phi)|_{(1,0,0)}$. Is it correct? I'm not sure at all. $f\circ \phi= [s_1+is_2:s_3+i\sqrt{1-s_1^2-s_2^2-s_3^2}]$ explicitly

Comment: I don't really know anything about differential geometry to be honest. If you want someone to check your solution you should rather start a new question and ask for verification there. I was only able to answer your original question here.